# How to manage GST tax rate in Magento 2?

Tags: php, magento, magento2.2

How can I form my e-commerce project in Magento 2?

I want to manage an Indian GST in Magento.

I am following [this tutorial](https://magecomp.com/blog/create-indian-gst-tax-rule-magento-2/) to manage GST and SGST.

By changing this code, with this one, how can I manage different tax based on price if price is smaller than 1000 (than 5 |%) and if price is more than 1000% (than 12%)?

Comment: Generally reading the documentation or getting started is a good idea to learn the basics of a system: https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/getting-started.html

Comment: This is not a free code writing service. What did you try so far? Please [edit] your question and post your code as a [mcve]! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?